# JWPlayer Where do I put the HD Quality Toggling embed code

Tags: html, video, iframe, jwplayer

I understand that there is a [tutorial](https://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1428524-hd-quality-toggling) for how to add a video quality selector to your JWPlayer video player and it gives you an embed code example for you to modify. I've modified it and added the information that is specific to my video but I don't know where I'm supposed to add this piece of code. I used the embed code for a video player in my website (iframe, [mivprofit.com/video](http://mivprofit.com/video/)) but I want to add the quality selector and I tried putting the code right after the iframe (after the iframe closing tag, "`</iframe>`") like so:

```
<iframe src="//content.jwplatform.com/players/RUWONgkw-Ck5HCg68.html" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto" allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
<script>
    var playerInstance = jwplayer("myElement");
    playerInstance.setup({
    image: "http://www.mivprofit.com/video/thumbnail.jpg",
    sources: [{
        file: "http://www.mivprofit.com/video/video.mp4",
        label: "1080p"
        },{
        file: "http://www.mivprofit.com/video/video720.mp4",
        label: "720p"
        },{
        file: "http://www.mivprofit.com/video/video480.mp4",
        label: "480p"
        },{
        file: "http://www.mivprofit.com/video/video360.mp4",
        label: "360p",
        "default": "true"
        }]
    });
</script>
```

But that doesn't seem to do anything so I guess that's not where that's supposed to go. Thanks in advance for any help.

Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add this code in the html from where your video is opening i.e.

```
//content.jwplatform.com/players/RUWONgkw-Ck5HCg68.html
```